# How to insert html into QTextEdit from clipboard via ctrl+V?

Tags: html, c++, qt, clipboard

I have program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    QApplication app(argc, argv);       
    QTextEdit te;
    te.setHtml("<!DOCTYPE html>"
        "<html>"
        "<body style = \"background-color:powderblue;\">"
        "<h1>My First Heading< / h1>"
        "<p>My first paragraph.< / p>"
        "< / body>"
        "< / html>");
    te.resize(500, 300);
    te.show();  
    return app.exec();  
}
```

This program creates the following window:

[image: QTextEdit with html]

I have another program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    QApplication app(argc, argv);       
    QTextEdit te;   
    te.resize(500, 300);
    te.show();  
    return app.exec();  
}
```

But if I copy the text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

from clipboard by pressing ctrl+V into the window created by the program, I see:

[image: window with plain html text]

How can I rewrite my program to display html as in the first image?

Comment: Not easy to say if you don't show the code. Is the behaviour different when you type the text instead of pasting it?

Comment: Read up from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html

Comment: You may also want to read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class TextEdit : public QTextEdit{
public:
    TextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QTextEdit(parent)
    {}
protected:
    void insertFromMimeData(const QMimeData *source){
        if(source->hasText()){
            setHtml(source->text());
        }
        else{
            QTextEdit::insertFromMimeData(source);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot paste html code directly with indented spaces. Try to copy it on MS word first and then from there, paste it anywhere else.